# Is there any application to generate Excel files with wizard?

Tags: java, excel

As I know JReport is for DBs , I want to generate several Excel files with JAVA,is there any application like JReport that handle it via template or wizard?

Answer (score 1):

Two that come to mind

1. [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library)
2. [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/java/excel-component.aspx)

I've used JasperReports before and that one definitely can generate excel as well as PDF and HTML off templates.